Error import : "File import callback not supported" (using remappings) [Pyth Network]
Im following the "create a contract" part in the tutorial of Pyth Network (https://docs.pyth.network/price-feeds/create-your-first-pyth-app/evm/part-1) and i have this error in the import. Does anyone knows what can it be ? im using the last version of Juan Blanco extension of Solidity.
Inside remappings.txt i have: @pythnetwork/pyth-sdk-solidity/=node_modules/@pythnetwork/pyth-sdk-solidity

Error: Source "@pythnetwork/pyth-sdk-solidity/IPyth.sol" not found: File import callback not supported(6275)
I already tried changing the default workspace compiler but it didn't work.

Instead of using remappings.txt, add this line to your foundry.toml file:
remappings = [
    "@pythnetwork/pyth-sdk-solidity/=node_modules/@pythnetwork/pyth-sdk-solidity"
]


Don't forget to install IPyth.sol.
https://docs.pyth.network/price-feeds/create-your-first-pyth-app/evm/part-1#install-the-pyth-sdk
